# How to convert .po to .mo files via CentOS command line?

Tags: linux, centos

I have .po and .mo files in my CentOS server. After I use `vi` to edit the .po file, is there a way that I can convert it to .mo through the command line?

P.S. please consider CentOS, thanks.

Comment: FYI, that's the [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html) format.

Answer (score 33):

In deb based distros: apt-get install gettext

I assume there's something similar in centos.

Then can use:

```
msgfmt messages.po -o messages.mo
```

Comment: you can edit your .po file with [poedit](https://poedit.net/) software and use it to auto-convert it to .mo. The software is multiplatform.

Answer (score 9):

In CentOS

```
sudo yum install gettext
```

And then

```
msgfmt messages.po -o messages.mo
```